# Devops project management board in Google Cloud platform

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-console

Does the Google Cloud platform has the project management board like azure DevOps. If so please someone can provide the details

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Right now there is no such thing in GCP. There are other tools but nothing related to Project Management. I think becuase in general terms, this would not add much to what [GCP offers](https://cloud.google.com/docs/overview/cloud-platform-services):

- Platform as a service (PaaS).
- Functions as a service (FaaS).
- Containers as a service (CaaS).
- Infrastructure as a service (IaaS).
- Storage Services, Databases.
- BigData services, Machine Learning Services.

Anyway, if you have a general idea of how you would like to work and which products you think it could interact with, you can file a Feature Request on the [Public Issue Tracker](https://cloud.google.com/support/docs/issue-trackers) with as much as details as possible.

I found this post named [Google Project Management Doesn’t Exist… Now What?](https://toggl.com/blog/google-project-management-doesnt-exist) which you might find interesting.

I also found this about [G Suite tips for project management](https://support.google.com/a/users/answer/9283047?hl=en). The most relevant could be:

> Create dynamic project plans and Gantt charts in Sheets to manage your projects, assignments, and deadlines. Team members across the globe can update their progress directly in the spreadsheet so it's always up to date.